# Start Stop difference grouped by quarter hour

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table called **time** (example 1) containing several timestamps per day, they represent login and logout times.

The second table is called **time_intervals** which leaves me with the output of example 2.

I need to figure out the duration this user was logged in grouped by 15 minute slices.

Example 3 displays my desired result.

**Example 1 (time)**

```
start_time      | end_time            | duration_s | user | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-07 06:01:13 | 2017-02-07 07:03:19 | 3726       | x    |
2017-02-07 07:31:29 | 2017-02-07 08:00:00 | 3726       | x    |
2017...............   ...................   ....         .
```

**Example 2 (time_intervals)**

```
interval_start  | interval_end        | 
--------------------------------------------
2017-02-07 06:00:00 | 2017-02-07 06:14:59 |
2017-02-07 06:15:00 | 2017-02-07 06:29:59 |
2017-02-07 06:30:00 | 2017-02-07 06:44:59 |
2017-02-07 06:45:00 | 2017-02-07 06:59:59 |
2017-02-07 07:00:00 | 2017-02-07 07:14:59 |
2017............... | 2017...............
```

**Example 3 (desired output)**

```
interval_start      | interval_start      | duration_s | user | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-07 06:00:00 | 2017-02-07 06:14:59 | 826    | x    |
2017-02-07 06:15:00 | 2017-02-07 06:29:59 | 899    | x    |
2017-02-07 06:30:00 | 2017-02-07 06:44:59 | 899    | x    |
2017-02-07 06:45:00 | 2017-02-07 06:59:59 | 899    | x    |
2017-02-07 07:00:00 | 2017-02-07 07:14:59 | 199    | x    |
2017-02-07 07:15:00 | 2017-02-07 07:30:59 | 0      | x    |
2017-02-07 07:30:00 | 2017-02-07 07:44:59 | 810    | x    |
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work provided that `time_intervals` holds all 15 minute intervals to be displayed:

```
SELECT ti.interval_start,
       ti.interval_end,      
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, GREATEST(t.start_time, ti.interval_start), 
                             LEAST(t.end_time, ti.interval_end)) AS duration_s
FROM time_intervals AS ti
LEFT JOIN time AS t 
   ON t.start_time <= ti.interval_end AND t.end_time >= ti.interval_start
```

Comment: "provided that time_intervals holds all 15 minute intervals" hmm.